# Asynchronous I/O callback method concurrency

Tags: c++, concurrency, concurrent-programming, overlapped-io

I've implemented Asynchronous I/O with a callback where I'm worried about concurrency. I contest to you that since I'm always working with the same file and the OS file **physical** I/O is fundamentally a synchronous operation then I won't need a lock mechanism in my callback method - but I may very well be wrong here - enter SO :o) I have a buffer manager that puts the read data into its buffer cache when the read operation has completed and a state engine for each overlapped operation based on the EOverlappedStates enumeration states ; "I/O not started", "Success", and "Error". Do you think that I need locking in the callback method to ensure concurrency in a multithreaded program like ours?

Open file:

```
OS_FILE_HANDLE CUniformDiskInterface::OpenFile(const wchar_t *fileName, bool *fileExists, bool readData, bool writeData, bool overlap, 
bool disableDiskCache, bool disableOsCache, bool randomAccess, bool sequentalScan) {
// Set access method
DWORD desiredAccess = readData ? GENERIC_READ : 0;
desiredAccess |= writeData ? GENERIC_WRITE : 0;

// Set file flags
DWORD fileFlags = disableDiskCache ? FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH : 0;
fileFlags |= disableOsCache ? FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING : 0;
fileFlags |= randomAccess ? FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS : 0;
fileFlags |= sequentalScan ? FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN : 0;
fileFlags |= !fileFlags ? FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL : 0;
fileFlags |= overlap ? FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED : 0;

HANDLE hOutputFile = CreateFile(
    fileName,
    desiredAccess,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    fileFlags,
    NULL);
```

Read file:

```
_UINT64 CUniformDiskInterface::ReadFromFile(OS_FILE_HANDLE hFile, void *outData, _UINT64 bytesToRead, OVERLAPPED *overlapped, LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE completionRoutine) {
DWORD wBytesRead = 0;

BOOL result = completionRoutine ? 
    ReadFileEx(hFile, outData, (DWORD)(bytesToRead), overlapped, completionRoutine) : 
    ReadFile(hFile, outData, (DWORD)(bytesToRead), &wBytesRead, overlapped);

if (!result)
{
    int errorCode = GetLastError();
    if (errorCode != ERROR_IO_PENDING )
    {
        wstringstream err(wstringstream::in | wstringstream::out);
        err << L"Can't read sectors from file. [ReadFile] error #" << errorCode << L".";
        throw new FileIOException(L"CUniformDiskInterface", L"ReadFromFile", err.str().c_str(), GETDATE, GETFILE, GETLINE); 
    }
}

return (_UINT64)wBytesRead; }
```

Extended overlapped structure:

```
            /*!
        \enum EOverlappedStates
        \brief The different overlapped states
        \details Used as inter-thread communication while waiting for the I/O operation to complete 
        */
        enum EOverlappedStates
        {
            /** The I/O operation has not started or in in-progress */
            EOverlappedNotStarted, 

            /** The I/O operation is done and was successful */
            EOverlappedSuccess, 

            /** The I/O operation is done but there was an error */
            EOverlappedError
        };

        /*!
        \struct OverlappedEx
        \brief Extended overlapped structure
        */
        struct OverlappedEx : OVERLAPPED
        {           
            /** The buffer manager that is designated to cache the record when it's loaded */
            CBufferManager *bufferManger;

            /** Transaction ID related to this disk I/O operation */
            _UINT64 transactionId;

            /** Start disk sector of the record */
            _UINT64 startDiskSector;

            /** Buffer */
            void *buffer;

            /** Number of bytes in \c buffer */
            _UINT64 bufferSize;

            /** Current overlapped I/O state. Used for inter-thread communication while waiting for the I/O to complete */
            EOverlappedStates state;

            /** Error code, or \c 0 if no error */
            _UINT32 errorCode;
        };
```

Callback method:

```
    /*! \brief Callback routine after a overlapped read has completed
\details Fills the buffer managers buffer cache with the read data
\todo This callback method may be a bottleneck, so look into how to handle this better
*/
VOID WINAPI CompletedReadRoutine(DWORD dwErr, DWORD cbBytesRead, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverLap) 
{ 
    OverlappedEx *overlapped = (OverlappedEx*)lpOverLap;
    overlapped->errorCode = (_UINT32)dwErr;

    if (!dwErr && cbBytesRead) 
    { 
        overlapped->state = EOverlappedSuccess;
        overlapped->bufferManger->AddBuffer(overlapped->startDiskSector, overlapped->buffer, overlapped->bufferSize);
    }
    else
    {
        // An error occurred
        overlapped->state = EOverlappedError;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    _UINT64 startDiskSector = location / sectorByteSize;
void *buffer = bufferManager->GetBuffer(startDiskSector);
if (!buffer)
{
    /*
    The disk sector was not cached, so get the data from the disk and cache in internal memory with
    the buffer manager
    */
    buffer = new char[recordByteSize];

    // Create a overlapped structure to enable disk async I/O operations
    OverlappedEx *overlapped = new OverlappedEx;
    memset(overlapped, 0, sizeof(OverlappedEx));
    overlapped->Offset = (DWORD)(startDiskSector & 0xffffffffULL);
    overlapped->OffsetHigh = (DWORD)(startDiskSector >> 31ULL);
    overlapped->hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    overlapped->bufferManger = bufferManager;
    overlapped->startDiskSector = startDiskSector;
    overlapped->buffer = buffer;
    overlapped->bufferSize = recordByteSize;
    overlapped->state = EOverlappedNotStarted;

    // Read from disk
    diskApi.ReadFromFile(fileHandle, buffer, sectorByteSize, overlapped, CompletedReadRoutine);
    return overlapped;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the callback function will only ever be called on the same thread that called the `ReadFileEx` function and only when the thread is waiting for events to occur. So there are guaranteed no synchronisation issues between the call to `ReadFileEx` and the invocation of the callback.

This means that there is no need to synchronize access to the `OverlappedEx` data structure as long as only one thread tries to read into a particular instance of that structure, which is equivalent to reading a particular file only from one thread.
If you try to read a single file from multiple thread, it is likely that you encounter problems within Windows itself (I don't think the asynchronous I/O is thread-safe in itself), so locking a mutex won't help you in that case.

Comment: I'm aware that async I/O is not on the same thread - my code works fine and I'm only looking for feedback on the concurrency question. Perhaps I was not clear on this, but it's "may not be"/"is not" the same thread that later checks overlapped->state == EOverlappedNotStarted which again means the I/O operation has completed.

Comment: If multiple threads access the same data, you need either locks or atomic types/operations on the data to guarantee integrity.

Comment: Well, in general that is correct, Bart. But as I wrote I contend that since **physical** I/O is fundamentally synchronious from the OS when accessing the same file I do not need and "additional" locking since the OS has already "taken care of that" by its syncronious nature.

Comment: I don't see how the physical I/O comes into this. If you have multiple threads accessing the `OverlappedEx::state` member, you need some kind of synchronisation on it. This would be needed even if the reading thread does synchronous I/O instead of asynchronous I/O.